# EntityFramework Core deletes entity with included entites that has been read

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

For some reason, when I read data from my database and makes a SaveChangesAsync() on my database context, the entity that have been loaded in with its relations will be deleted from the database.

```
Category tools = new("Tools");
ProductType p = new("Hammer", 25, tools);
Ware w1 = new("S1", p, new("Floor"));
Ware w2 = new("S2", p, new("Floor"));
Ware w3 = new("S3", p, new("Floor"));
Ware w4 = new("S4", p, new("Floor"));
Ware w5 = new("S5", p, new("Floor"));
p.AddWare(w1);
p.AddWare(w2);
p.AddWare(w3);
p.AddWare(w4);
p.AddWare(w5);

unitOfWork.ProductTypeRepository.Create(p);

ProductType selected = unitOfWork.ProductTypeRepository.GetByIdAsync(46).Result;
ProductType selected2 = unitOfWork.ProductTypeRepository.GetByIdAsyncWithRelationships(50).Result;
Console.WriteLine("____");
var done = unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync().Result;
Console.WriteLine(done);
```

The differences above is that the data in `selected` is not deleted, while `selected2` is.

The two methods are the following

```
public async Task<ProductType> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _shopDbContext.ProductTypes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProductTypeId == id);
        }
```

and

```
public async Task<ProductType> GetByIdAsyncWithRelationships(int id)
        {
            return await _shopDbContext.ProductTypes
                .Include(p => p.OfferProductTypes)
                    .ThenInclude(op => op.Offer)
                .Include(p => p.Wares)
                .Include(p => p.Category)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProductTypeId == id);
        }
```

From my MSSQL database server profiler I can see the following

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM [Ware]
WHERE [WareId] = @p0;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [Ware]
WHERE [WareId] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [Ware]
WHERE [WareId] = @p2;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [Ware]
WHERE [WareId] = @p3;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [Ware]
WHERE [WareId] = @p4;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

',N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 int,@p4 int',@p0=246,@p1=247,@p2=248,@p3=249,@p4=250
```

and

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM [ProductTypes]
WHERE [ProductTypeId] = @p5;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

',N'@p5 int',@p5=50
```

Meanwhile the code I have in SaveChangesAsync() in UnitOfWork

```
public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    var ct = _context.ChangeTracker;
    foreach(var e in ct.Entries())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Entity.GetType().Name + " : " +e.State);
    }
    return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

displays the following

```
____
ProductType : Unchanged
0
```

It does not even indicate that a ProductType has been added together with its wares and Category. The database is updated.

However, sometimes it does display the changes

```
ProductType : Added
Category : Added
Ware : Added
Location : Added
Ware : Added
Location : Added
Ware : Added
Location : Added
Ware : Added
Location : Added
Ware : Added
Location : Added
ProductType : Deleted
Ware : Deleted
Ware : Deleted
Ware : Deleted
Ware : Deleted
Ware : Deleted
ProductType : Unchanged
Category : Unchanged
```

Here is a link to the git repository https://github.com/BenjaminElifLarsen/Shopping---MCVE in a MCVE form. The files is `program` in ShoppingCli and the repositories in Ipl.Repositories and `UnitOfWork` in Ipl.Services

------ Update -----
I have just tried circumvent my unit of work and called the database context directly and any entity that is loaded together with related entities using Include() and ThenInclude() are deleted.

Comment: Can you turn this into an MCVE? I'm happy to give a go at running it on my machine and see if I can repro it; it might be a bug that should be fed back to the EF team.

Comment: To summarize a comment chain on my answer: I suspect there are other threads running in your runtime which are causing the deletes. The last snippet you show contains 3 `ProductType` messages, and an EF context can only perform one operation in a single `SaveChanges` call for a given entity, so these `ProductType` messages cannot possibly refer to the same entity in the same context and the same `SaveChanges` call three times. It might help to log more information, e.g. a JSON-serialized dump of each entity in the tracker, which can help explain which entity is being referenced when.

Comment: @CaiusJard I will try and turn it into a MCVE as soon as possible, it is not something I have the most experience with, so it might take a while.

Comment: @Flater I will try and add some more logging. Regarding the possiblity of other threads, there should only be a single thread running.

Comment: You really have to turn this into a [mre]. All of your code in an external source. Most people will just ignore your question and also, if the external source changes the question is useless.

Comment: @CaiusJard Here is a link to a MCVE version of the project https://github.com/BenjaminElifLarsen/Shopping---MCVE The run file is program in the ShoppingCli project. To change the ProductTypes that are retrived, you will need to change the two variables alwaysThere and willBeDeleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this took some digging into, but I believe I've come to the logical explanation:

Your DB entities are a bit wonky, and behave in ways EF can't tolerate

Here's what happens in a normal scenario (and this isn't the exact code the EF does, it's a sort of pseudo-explanation for simplicity):

You invoke a query, EF runs it, turns the received data into objects and wires them up into a graph. Your query is essentially this:

```
        await ctx.ProductTypes
            .Include(p => p.OfferProductTypes)
            .Include(p => p.Wares)
            .Include(p => p.Category)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProductTypeId == 4);
```

EF will make a `ProductType`, EF will make a `Category`, EF will make 5 `Ware`s. `Category` is the parent of `ProductType`, `ProductType` is the parent of `Ware`

After it's made the `ProductType` and `Category`, EF wants to wire up a bidirectional relationship between `ProductType` and `Category` so it sets `theProductType.Category = theCategory` and because it's many:1 (pt:c) EF makes a collection to hold the ProductTypes and sets `theCategory.ProductTypes = theCollectionOfProductTypes`. It then fills `theCollectionOfProductTypes` with all the ProductType instances it knows about

In pseudocode terms EF does this:

```
ProductType theProductType = get(...) //gets product type 4, we don't care so much how
Category theCategory = get(...) //gets the category, we don't care so much how

List<ProductType> theCollectionOfProductTypes = new(); //it's probably not a list, but it doesn't matter

theProductType.Category = theCategory;
theCategory.ProductTypes = theCollectionOfProductTypes;

theCollectionOfProductTypes.Add(theProductType);
```

With me so far? Here's the rub:

When EF gave your Category the collection of ProductTypes it made, you made another (separate) collection out of it:

```
    public IEnumerable<ProductType> ProductTypes { 
      get => _productType; 
      private set => _productType = value.ToHashSet(); 
    }
```

Skipping over the part where making this IEnumerable is a bad idea because you can't write to an IEnumerable (which makes it harder to add ProductTypes to your Category) and getting stright to the bit where you `ToHashSet` it, you've disconnected your graph from EF's reality. If we add a bit to hold what EF gave you:

```
    public IEnumerable<ProductType> ProductTypes {
        get => _productType;
        private set  {
            _productType = value.ToHashSet();
            _whatEfHolds = value;
        }
    }
    private object _whatEfHolds;
```

[image]

You can see that your category's "list of producttypes" has 0 items, whereas the one EF filled up when it was wiring the graph up, has 1 item (the ProductType id 4 we downloaded)

All will be fine, until we ask EF to detect changes between your graph and its own; when it pulls your Category's ProductTypes property, it will receive 0 entities and assume you removed them:

```
dbug: 2021-10-20 12:34:56.789 CoreEventId.CollectionChangeDetected[10804] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
      0 entities were added and 1 entities were removed from navigation 'Category.ProductTypes' on entity with key '{CategoryId: 4}'.
dbug: 2021-10-20 12:34:56.789 CoreEventId.StateChanged[10807] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
      The 'ProductType' entity with key '{ProductTypeId: 4}' tracked by 'ShopDbContext' changed state from 'Unchanged' to 'Modified'.
dbug: 2021-10-20 12:34:56.789 CoreEventId.CascadeDeleteOrphan[10003] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update)
      An entity of type 'ProductType' with key '{ProductTypeId: 4}' changed to 'Deleted' state due to severed required relationship to its parent entity of type 'Category'.
```

EF marked your ProductType as deleted, and then cascaded that out to the Wares too

What to do about it? Personally, I think you have too much logic and messing around in your DB ents; they should be much simpler affairs that just hold data, and maybe have some methods for slightly more advanced logic (but perhaps a lot of that would be put into your mapper) in a partial class. A Category should perhaps look more like this (note, it's called a TestCategories because I scaffed it from the DB, and thats what the DB table is called):

```
public partial class TestCategories
{
    public TestCategories()
    {
        ProductTypes = new HashSet<ProductTypes>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductTypes> ProductTypes { get; set; }
}
```

A ProductType like this:

```
public partial class ProductTypes
{
    public ProductTypes()
    {
        OfferProductType = new HashSet<OfferProductType>();
        Ware = new HashSet<Ware>();
    }

    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual TestCategories Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OfferProductType> OfferProductType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ware> Ware { get; set; }
}
```

But the main takeaway; be careful/avoid doing stuff (like `ToHashSet`) on the ents EF gives you when it's populating your object graph

Comment: That solved the problem. Thansks a lot for the help. The reason I were using HashSet was that I have read that was a good idea to prevent duplications of entities, but now I know not to use it.

Comment: It's not about not using HashSet; EF's own scaffolded classes use it/the collection EF gives you is a HashSet. The problem is because you took the hashset it gave you, and made another one, which is conceptually equivalent of Clear() ing it before you save it (which disconnects the relationships, which makes EF delete records). You'd get the same problem if you'd called ToList(), or anything else that causes another instance of a collection, separated from the collection EF built

Comment: To get started with EF and get an idea of how it's best to shape your entities, it's probably sensible to make the DB (any DB) first, and get EF to scaffold entities from the DB, then look at how it built them. *Try not to deviate too much from that pattern* - keep your DB entities simple. If they need populating in weird ways with arcane logic, put that logic in some external mapping class, that way your entity graph remains simple to understand and interpret, lest you end up with the same situation you did here

Comment: The other thing in the code, which I touched on - you've made your holder variable an `IEnumerable<whatever>`  and then you stored a hashset in it - you *can* do that because a hashset is enumerable, but it makes it a much bigger pain in the ass to work with in terms of adding entities; you can't say `myCategory.ProductTypes.Add(someProductType)` because you can't add to an enumerable. You have to eg remember it's a HashSet and cast it: `(myCategory.ProductTypes as HashSet<ProductType).Add(someProductType)`

Comment: "i can just do that every time then" you might say, but that's like keeping everything in an `object` and casting it every time you want to use it: `object o = new StringBuilder(); (o as StringBuilder).Append("...");` - noone does this; they just use a surface type that is easier, in general, to work with. If you take a look at the two classes I put at the end - i didn't write those, EF wrote them, so you could regard them as being "a pattern that EF team assert as being easy to work with".

Answer (score 0):

None of the code you posted involved a delete action, so I'm unsure where the DELETE statements are coming from, but it's not in the code provided. I also think you're paddling up the wrong creek in trying to explain why `selected` and `selected2` are different.

The issue isn't that your entity has been "deleted". The issue is that one of these queries can be answered using the change tracker's cache (`selected`), and the other cannot (`selected2`).

In short, EF caches the entities you work with. Whether you attach a new entity or you fetch one from the database, EF tracks it based on its type + PK value. If you request it again, then EF will give you the cached version.

```
unitOfWork.ProductTypeRepository.Create(p);
```

You have added the product type, but you have not yet saved your changes, therefore, the added product type provisionally lives in the change tracker (= cache) but not yet in the database.

```
_shopDbContext.ProductTypes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProductTypeId == id)
```

Here, in your first query, you are asking for your entity (and only this entity) based on its type and PK value. EF checks its cache, and notices that it already has this entity cached. It's the entity you added (but have not yet saved) in the previous step. Therefore, EF give you back a reference to the cached entity that it already knew about. EF never even bothered to talk to the database.

```
_shopDbContext.ProductTypes
    .Include(p => p.OfferProductTypes)
      .ThenInclude(op => op.Offer)
    .Include(p => p.Wares)
    .Include(p => p.Category)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProductTypeId == id);
```

Here, in your second query, you are asking for much more than just your main entity. You're asking for all of its related entities.

This is inherently not something that the change tracker can account for. Even if it knows about several entities (e.g. wares) that belong to the product type, it **(a)** cannot be sure that it knows about **all** related wares (maybe there are more in the database), and **(b)** has to look up the categories based on the product type FK, not the ware PK, which is not something EF's cache is built to do.

Because of this, EF must invariably go to the database for your data. And EF does not perform a hybrid approach, whereby it uses some of the cache and some of the real data. It's always one or the other. Since *some* of the data needs to be fetched from the actual database, *all* of the requested data is being fetched from the database.

Because EF is now hitting the database, the database returns nothing, because **you never saved your new product type to the database** (yet). Therefore, EF tells you that this product type doesn't exist, because the database correctly stated that it doesn't exist (in the database).

Comment: Just trying to rationalize what is presented in the question, with what is presented in the answer - you appear to be saying that creating an entity, adding it to a context, then querying the context for a second (different) entity (with a different PK) will cause related data from the second entity to be deleted, and this is expected?

Comment: @CaiusJard: You seem to have missed the first paragraph. The presented code in the question does not include any delete action on EF's behalf, so I cannot explain who of what is triggering these deletions. All I can say is that it's not because of the presented code. However, the presented issue with `selected2` seemingly not containing the data that `selected` does contain, is not caused by a delete action. It is already explained by how EF handles its change tracker both as a cache of unsaved changes, and a cache for the retrieval of entities.

Comment: The problem still appear if I do not add any data to the database. If I just query the database for two entities in it, the one loaded with related entties will always be deleted.  The entity and its related entities are being received by the program.

Comment: OK, but even all the IDs Ben has used when pulling data from the DB, are different.. I can't work out how the answer fits with the question. It's useful info, but the complaint seems to be essentially "I added entity with ID 25, queried entity with ID 46, queried with entity 50 and all 50's related data got deleted - why?".. I'm not sure what question the answer answers but it seems unexpected that adding one ent would cause another in the CT's memory to be deleted

Comment: @CaiusJard: Then there are two problems happening at the same time. One I can explain based on the presented code, and one I can't. I answered the one which I could. I never claimed the deletes weren't happening, just that the presented code isn't the one doing the deletion. EF does not delete objects unless instructed to (through `Remove`, unreferencing a cross join, or migrations), none of which happen in the presented code.

Comment: @CaiusJard: Additionally, EF only tracks **one** operation per tracked entity (this is a known behavior, manifesting in e.g. that you can't add and update something in the same transaction). The fact that `ProductType : [...]` appears three times in the log suggests that there are either three different product type entities being tracked in this context, or that multiple contexts are tracking their own product type entity (and are all individually logging to the console). The presented code only explains the existence of the `ProductType : Added` line, not the other two.

Comment: Yes, surely an Added item is always added no matter how many times you change its properties before/after adding to the changetracker (but before saving to db). It only becomes Modified if it's changed after EF knows it's been saved to the DB..

Comment: @CaiusJard: However, if you were to explicitly do an update, the change tracker overwrites the `Added` state with the `Changed` state (same happens when you call `Remove`, which overwrites to the `Deleted` state), and thus only tries to update (or remove) an existing entry (which causes an error, because it did not exist yet and can't be updated/removed). This is precisely why the shown output does not match with only the code that has been shown. There are presumably other threads doing their own thing during the same runtime, but I cannot troubleshoot this based on the presented information.

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't call Update, nor did Ben. I'm not trying to make this a "let's get Flater to tell us all the ways we can fool the EF CT into making a mistake".. Perhaps it would be best if we avoid much further what-iffing and wait for an mCVE we can run locally and see what we can figure out, if indeed we can repro the behavior

Comment: @CaiusJard: The point I'm making is that this proves that the posted code cannot _by itself_ explain the posted output; and therefore the part of the question which you pointed out as not being answered by me cannot actually be answered based on the question as is.